# TimeLimiter is not stopping the method execution and going to next step

Tags: java, settimeout, timeoutexception, time-limiting

Currently, we are facing an issue with a read timeout for a DB call. I am trying to add a time limit on the method to wait for only 3 seconds. If the method doesn't return data in 3 seconds my execution goes to the next line. I tried to achieve this with the below code but the control is not moving to the next step even after 3 seconds. In the below code I am adding a timeout for method b execution, When method b takes more than 3 seconds to return the control should go to catch block and go to the next line of code i.e. callingMethodC. But the control is not coming out even after 3 seconds am I missing anything? Can anyone suggest?

```
private String methodA(){
TimeLimiter timeLimiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter();
                    try {
                    String  data = timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(
                                () -> methodB("abc"), 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Exception while read data from db after 3 seconds");
                    }
callmethodc();
}

private String methodB(String abc){
String result = dbrepository.get(abc);
return result;
}
```

Comment: `methodB("abc)` ... You're missing a `"` there.

Comment: i just edited.. it was a typo mistake